# How to disable all form_for input fields in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to DRY up my Rails application a bit, so I would like to render a form in my `show` view but *disable* all input fields.

```
// show.html.erb

<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Javascript

One way would be to do it using JS. Include a `div` with a specific class in the show view :

```
// show.html.erb

<div class='disable_input'>
  <%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then in your JS file :

```
$('.disable_input :input').prop('disabled', true);
```

### Rails

If you want to actually generate it server side, you can pass a variable to your partial that will tell the partial if it has to add the disabled option on each field. It's a bit more work though!

Using a variable, you could do something like this :

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f, :disabled => true %>
<% end %>
```

In the partial :

```
<% disabled ||= false  
   #We do this so if disabled is not passed to the partial it doesn't crash. 
   # We default it to false 
%>

<% # Then for all your fields, add disabled: disabled %>
<%= f.text_field :some_attribute, disabled: disabled %>
```

### Form builder

Edit : actually, one way to avoid explicitly passing `disabled` everywhere would be to create a `Custom form builder`. There's some good resources talking about it, like this one : http://johnford.is/writing-a-custom-formbuilder-in-rails/

In this example, it's done for `onkeypress`, shouldn't be hard to adapt for your case!

Comment: OK, thanks. It's easy to do with jQuery but what if someone has Javascript turned off. Actually I was hoping there is a more solid way to do this...

Comment: Edited my answer. Can't think of a cleaner way to do it. If there's a way to avoid passing `disabled` to each form element, it would great.

Comment: Indeed I ended up creating a form builder as you suggested. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: How did it work out? Can you share the solution in your post to help future readers? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I just followed Ryan Bate's [form builder tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders) which is really great for this purpose.

Answer (score 21):

You can wrap all fields in `<fieldset disabled>`

```
// show.html.erb

<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this is awesome!

Answer (score -2):

You can use stylesheets for this thing.

The show action might be in controller say 'Project', hence you might be having a file in stylesheets with the name of your controller.

Now enclose your form in show.html.erb in a div, and give it a unique id ,say 'disable_input', that you wont be giving to any element in any page.

Now disable all input fields in you css under this div. You can write it like this..

disable_input input{
# whatever you want to do
}

Hence no need to code.

Comment: He wants to add the `disabled` property to each input. To the best of my knowledge, you can't do that using CSS

Comment: Yes, I've just done some research and there's no way to `disable` a HTML input field using CSS only. Would have been nice though!

Comment: You can not disable an input or inputs by using CSS only as it involves more than just making them "look" disabled.